# How can I store values after an R shiny app has run?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to download stock data through an interactive R shiny app. I am asking for the stock index name and the dates to download the data for. After running the app I can print the downloaded data but I can't store them to use them later on. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks

Here's my code:

```
  ui= fluidPage(
  titlePanel("download stock data "),

  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
  helpText("Select an index to examine the stocks it contains.   
         Information will be collected from Yahoo finance."),
  textInput("symb", "Symbol", ""),

  dateRangeInput("dates",
                 "Date range",
                 start = "2009-12-28",
                 end = "2019-09-12")),
  mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("out"))),
br(),
br(),
submitButton()
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {

dataInput <- reactive({tq_get(tq_index(input$symb),
           get = "stock.prices",from=input$dates[1],to=input$dates[2],
           complete_cases = TRUE,verbose=TRUE)

})

output$out=renderPrint(dataInput())

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Several ways you can try to do that: 1. use `shiny::downloadHandler` to download data. 2. Save `dataInput()` to disk by using `writeLines()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you use a persistent data solution: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

I have written shiny apps with data caching which could be used for this as well. My suggestion would be to add an action button in the `ui` (let's call it `save_dat`). Then include the following in `server`:

```
observeEvent(input$save_dat, {
  saveRDS(dataInput(), paste0("SOME_PATH/", input$symb, ".rds"))
}
```

Then you can read these data objects from this app, another app, other .Rmd reports, or just in your own ad hoc analyses. It's a good idea to have some type of auto deletion for old data objects though!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This could be a solution but what I want to do is to assign the downloaded data in a variable or a list, so that I can use them later. I don't want to read them from a file afterwards.